# Problems installing older version of scikit-learn on python 3.7 and 3.5 for SVM model compatibility

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-3.5, python-3.7

I have to implement an svm classifier into an older version of scikit-learn. The model I trained on scikit-learn (0.20.3) does not seem to work with the version that's being used  for my project (0.15.2), it returns: AttributeError:'SVC' object has no attribute '_imp1'. To solve this issue I would like to install an older version of scikit-learn in order retrain my model on that version. I keep getting the following errors when trying to install an older version of scikit-learn for both python 3.5 and 3.7 on Windows 10:

> ```
> c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\include\pystate.h(209): note:
> ```
>
> see declaration of '_ts'
>       sklearn\cluster_dbscan_inner.cpp(5971): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
>       c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
>       sklearn\cluster_dbscan_inner.cpp(5972): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
>       c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
>       sklearn\cluster_dbscan_inner.cpp(5973): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
>       c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\include\pystate.h(209): note: see declaration of '_ts'
>
> ```
> ----------------------------------------
> ```
>
> Command ""c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe" -u -c "import
>   setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Pat2\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-77bzkmyc\scikit-learn\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open' , open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\Pat2\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4hjlpz98\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-exte rnally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\Pat2\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-77bzkmyc\scikit-learn\

The log that is printed out is very long so I'm not sure which part to copy here. The following error is also printed but does not stop the installing process:

> error: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe
>   /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD
>   -IC:\Users\Pat2\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python3 7\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Isklearn\svm\src\libsvm
>   -IC:\Users\Pat2\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\include
>   -I"c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\include" -I"c:\program files (x86) \python37-32\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include" -I"C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program
>   Files (x 86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\shared"
>   -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\winrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\W indows Kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsklearn\svm\libsvm.c
>   /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\sklearn\svm\libsvm.obj" failed with
>   exit status 2

The following message also appears often:

> No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils;
>   trying from distutils

So far I have tried these things:

- Installed cython 0.27.3
- Installed atlas
- Manually installing scikit-learn 0.15.3 through setup.py
- Retrieving scikit-learn 0.15.3 directly from Github
- Reinstalling Microsoft visual studio C++
- Tried it on my other computer which resulted in the same problem

But none of these actions has changed the outcome of installing scikit-learn 0.15.3

EDIT:

1. I'm having the same issue when trying to install scikit-learn 0.19.0
2. Added more info to the first error log

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pip install setuptools --upgrade
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it did not make any difference though. But since the other (working) device has an older version of numpy installed I tried to roll back my numpy version as well (to 1.13.0). Rolling back failed with a similar error, pointing at the c++ building tool. So right now I am reinstalling microsoft visual c++ build tools in order to see if this is the problem.

Comment: If the problem with a building tool showed up, try upgrading `setuptools`.

Comment: Both setuptools and numpy are up to date, yet the problem stil persists. In order to not be stuck I decided to train the model on the device (raspberry pi 3), but I guess this is not an optimal solution. I still get the errors when installing older versions of numpy and scikit-learn(on both my computers actually).